# Is there a more pythonic way to multiply two tensors?

Tags: python, numpy, performance

I would like to multiply two tensors of different size in specific dimension. For example:

```
A=numpy.random.random((10, 10, 10, 10,200))
B=numpy.random.random((10000,200))
```

I used dumpy's einsum before:

```
res = numpy.einsum('abcdx,yx->abcdy', A,B, optimize=True)
```

A faster option seems to be the following:

```
Ar = A.reshape(10**4,200)
z = np.matmul(Ar,B.T)
res = z.reshape(10,10,10,10,10000)
```

Is there a faster way to do that?

Comment: Your `numpy.einsum` example raises a `ValueError`

Comment: It is hard to understand what result do you expect, since none of your two methods make sense and could produce a result of any sort. The `einsum` doesn't contain the correct number of indices (6 and 1, when arguments have 5 and 2 dimensions). And the `matmul` method produces a 10000x10000 matrix, when you seem to expect to produce a 10x10x10x10x200 array from it.

Comment: Generally speaking tho, the answer is probably "it depends". Reshape based method would be probably the more efficent (if then the matmul does exactly what is wanted and nothing more), under the condition that the reshape is possible without a copy. Which is the case in your example, since you start from brand new freshly made contiguous numpy arrays. But could not be the case if data of the source array is not contiguous.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers.
Very sorry, should have tested the minimal example before posting it. I updated my question and corrected the code.

Comment: I'll quibble with uour "pythonic" label.  If it runs without error it is 'pythonic'; speed has nothing to do with it.  This is a `numpy` speed issue.  You have large enough arrays that memory use can affect speeds in one way or other.  `A@B.T` also works, but is slower than your reshape version.  Where possible `matmul` uses the fast BLAS library.  With more than 2 dimensions, the leading ones are treated as a 'batch'; your reshape avoids that.  `einsum` with optimize can also work with `BLAS`.

Comment: Well, there is not much to do here. `einsum` is relatively good (at least on my machine). It runs in parallel and takes only 0.27s. There is 40e9 floating-point operations to do so it reach 148 GFlops. This is close to the maximum speed of my processor (AFAIR, Linpack reached ~150 GFlops and the theoretical peak is 200 GFlops). What is the precise reference of the target processor used and the resulting timings?

Comment: Note you can use server GPUs to do that quite faster if you have access to one (mainstream PCs are useless for this computation -- server GPUs are a bit expensive though).